# AWS Lambda automate S3 Policies

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a piece of code on lambda that attaches a policy to all S3 buckets when they are created.

Really stuck on where to even begin! Any help is appreciated.

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyS3PublicObjectACL",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::private-bucket1/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::private-bucket1"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEqualsIgnoreCaseIfExists": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                    "public-read",
                    "public-read-write",
                    "authenticated-read"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Above is the code I have written so far, I want it to be applied to ALL buckets, so will need to pass bucket names into the policy and would like to be able to attach the policy to all new buckets using lambda.

Comment: If your bucket policy is going to be the same except the bucket name, create a JSON file with the bucket policy and a static string like S3_BUCKET_NAME which you will replace with the bucket name. Have the Lambda invoked whenever a bucket is created. This can be done using CloudWatch / CloudTrail / AWS Config. You need to use `put_bucket_policy` API in boto3 to add the bucket policy.

Comment: I'm trying to test the function manually for one bucket right now. How do I call the JSON policy from the Python code? e.g. policy='/s3bucketpolicy.json' - It throws me an error if I do this.

Comment: I am assuming that s3bucketpolicy.json is present in the same location as your lambda handler. If so, `/` is wrong. Replace it with './' and give it a try.